# Unit tests on Java ( Mockito ) that run both on Windows and on Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, mockito

I have a Java project that will run both on Windows and Linux. It has wrappers for Windows specific OS calls and for Linux ether. How can I write unit tests that will run on each platform without a problem?
I've tried to mock the specific OS calls, but I got the following error:

```
NTFSHandlerUnitTest > impersonateTest() FAILED
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'Advapi32': Native library (linux-x86-64/libAdvapi32.so) not found in resource path
```

My test:

```
@InjectMocks
WinFSHandler handler;

@Mock
WindowsAuthProviderImpl provider;

@Mock
Advapi32Util.Privilege privilege;

@Mock
ConfigClientProperties.Credentials cred;

@BeforeEach
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
void impersonateTest() {

    IWindowsIdentity identity = mock(IWindowsIdentity.class);
    when(provider.logonDomainUserEx(any(), any(), any(), anyInt(), anyInt() ))
            .thenReturn(identity);
    when(privilege.enable()).thenReturn(null);

    boolean result = handler.Impersonate();

    assertTrue(result);
}
```

Comment: Add a windows profile and a linux profile for your tests... and separate the tests

Comment: But when I will run test coverage this OS specific code will be considered uncovered.